# Having trouble in customizing text, text position, fontweight and etc

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble customizing the font aspects, and position of my text in the code below. I want to put 'Bula Anvisa', centralized and bold, with a clickable link to its specific documents online. I begin "coding" this app in appinventor, there I had almost everything in order, but with flutter it's being very hard, although I'm loving learning this language. This is my first app and experience with code. After everything is in order, I'd like to make it a beautiful and fluid app. One step at a time.

I'm receiving the message

Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.

```
   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class analgesicos extends StatefulWidget {
  const analgesicos({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<analgesicos> createState() => _analgesicosState();
}

class _analgesicosState extends State<analgesicos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,

        appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Analgésicos',style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf',
        fontSize: 22,

    ),),
    ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200.0),
        child: (
        Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),),
          Container(width: 240.0,
            height: 42.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: const Color(0xffc5fce1),
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Text(
                'Não-opióides',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  height: 1.7,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
height: 15),

          const Material(
            child: (const Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Ácido acetilsalicílico'),
                subtitle: Text('''Apresentação: Comprimidos simples de 500 ou 650 mg
                Indicação: Antipirético e analgésico.
                Posologia odontológica: Uso interno (via oral)
                Tomar 1 comprimido de 6/6 horas.'''),
              ),
            )),
          ),

                    const Material(
            child: (const Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Bula ANVISA'),
              ),
            )),
          ),
                            ],)
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the code runnable.

Comment: Highlight the line where positional arguments error is thrown